# Are binomial regression and Poisson regression with an offset to 1 substantially different?

Tags: binomial-distribution, model-selection, negative-binomial-distribution, poisson-binomial-distribution

I know that negbin can approximate the betabin distribution, especially when the probability of hitting the max is low (events are more rare). **If the offset of a negative binomial regression transforms the outcome to be between 0 and 1, is it substantially different from using beta-binomial regression?**

For context: My research question is: *"Are my predictors associated with the number of risk behaviors (out of a possible 22) that participants reported doing in the last thirty days?"*

Therefore, my DV is a count/proportion of risk behaviors out of a possible 22 that participants report in the last month. Of the sample of 222 people, only 5 have scores higher than 17, and there is significant overdispersion. I'm deciding on whether I should use a beta-binomial model or a negative binomial model with an *offset* indicating the number of questions that individuals were asked (20, 21, or 22, depending on specific conditions).

**Questions:**

1. If the offset of a negative binomial regression transforms the outcome to be between 0 and 1, is it substantially different from using beta-binomial regression?

   - Using AIC to compare, my results suggest that adding an offset to the Negbin models destroys model fit (tripling AIC). Including it as a factored predictor has little effect on the AIC, and the coefficients are not significantly different from 0.
   - The beta-binomial approach and the negative binomial model without an offset provide comparable fit (AIC and Est/S.E. ratios).
2. Is it ever appropriate to use a negative binomial regression with an offset to obtain estimates of a proportion?
3. The negbin model (relative to the beta-binomial) without an offset has the best AIC, better standard errors, one less df, and can model parameters that won't work in the beta-binomial model, so I'm inclined to choose it). What would be the downside to choosing negbin without an offset as opposed to beta binomial?(bias, interpretation, etc.)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Q1: Well, you can see beta-binomial regression as modelling proportions in $[0,1]$, but a negative binomial regression with log of exposure is a rate, that is, events per time, and can well be larger than 1. This are very different models.  Most importantly, the variance structure is different.  When choosing a model you must think about what is most appropriate variance structure.

Q2: To obtain estimates of a rate, yes. Rates are not proportions.

Q3: You should not choose to use offset or note based on aic (or other fit criteria). Offset or not changes what you are modeling, so this is a modeling decision.  Or, stated more bluntly:  including an offset or not changes what question you are asking of the data, and it does not make any sense to let the data decide which *question you are asking*!

(In future, please, if you have three questions, ask three questions, not one)

Comment: Thanks for the help, @kjetil! I'll try to avoid asking multiple questions in the future--I just thought it might be avoiding more clutter since the questions were all related.